# How do i change index string to datetime in pandas?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to change the index string to index which is datetime in pandas dataframe.

```
    High    Low Open    Close   Volume  Adj Close
Date                        
1987-12-31  1.535714    1.495536    1.517857    1.500000    29400000.0  1.200883
1988-01-04  1.598214    1.508929    1.526786    1.598214    82600000.0  1.279513
1988-01-05  1.651786    1.580357    1.642857    1.593750    77280000.0  1.275938
1988-01-06  1.607143    1.562500    1.607143    1.562500    67200000.0  1.250920
1988-01-07  1.598214    1.517857    1.553571    1.589286    53200000.0  1.272364
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2007-12-24  28.475714   27.827143   27.861429   28.400000   120050700.0 24.785059
2007-12-26  28.708570   28.117144   28.430000   28.421429   175933100.0 24.803761
2007-12-27  28.994286   28.257143   28.421429   28.367144   198881900.0 24.756376
2007-12-28  28.794285   28.125713   28.655714   28.547142   174911800.0 24.913471
2007-12-31  28.642857   28.250000   28.500000   28.297142   134833300.0 24.695290
```

To change the date format i have tried to use the

```
data['Date'] = data.to_datetime(data['Date'], format ='%Y-%m-%d')
```

However i am getting the following error:

How can i change the index to datetime format?

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pandas.to_datetime()` is not a method on the dataframe object but instead from `pandas` module itself. ([Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime))

Indexes can't be accessed using `df['Date']`. This syntax is for accessing columns.

If you want to access the index and change it's type to DateTime, try this:

```py
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: i used `data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format ='%Y-%m-%d')` but i got the following error: `KeyError: 'Date'` I changed df to data as it is in data

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "remove it and keep it as a new column" From what i understand the index is in string form but i want to change that to datetime index.

Comment: Why did you use `df.index` instead of `data.index`?

Comment: @newcoder, while testing I created dataframe with variable name `df`. Whereas, in your case it will be `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to revise the index named Date. It is not a column. Try this.

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Cell in Your date column is string? You should get the date column and get each string to date time by using datetime library.